# MPMediaPlayerController on iPhone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

How do we play a video using MPMoviePlayerController in sdk 4.0. Like 3.1 and higher, the play does not seem to work. Or it seems to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: what we really need on Stack Overflow is a new gold badge: "NDA Breaker" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I haven't signed any NDA as I haven't paid 99USD for it.

So First of MPMoviePlayerController use to play Music in the foreground by launching Quicktime player, now what it does is you have to pass it on the URI and it will play the same in the background, as why its not loading up I don't know because I haven't tested it.